# google sheets function won't run after another function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two google apps scripts functions ( plootorawtofinalforqbse() and myFunction() ) that work fine independently but I'd like to combine the two functions into one google apps script. If I do combine them, myfunction() does not move the columns

I can run them separately as different scripts and myfunction() works.

```html
function plootorawtofinalforqbse() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
var keep = [1,4,21]; // array of column numbers to keep
sheet.deleteRow(1);

for (var col=lastCol; col > 0; col--) {
if (keep.indexOf(col) == -1) {
// This isn't a keeper, delete it
sheet.deleteColumn(col);
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
 }
}
  
  };
function myFunction() {
const sheet = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Transaction Details");
sheet.moveColumns(sheet.getRange("A1"), 3);
}
```

How to I put them together into one google apps script?

[sheet link for testing script](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ayZK8XGdkKslOBf71MWedWWoQp5db28w0KS9N2wjmEo/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: When you want to run `myFunction()` after `plootorawtofinalforqbse()` was finished, for example, you can achieve this by putting `myFunction()` to the last line of the function of `plootorawtofinalforqbse()`. But when the columns you want to move are merged, such error occurs. So how about unmerging and testing again?

Comment: I apologize but there was no error. my mistake

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: The error message is gone but myfunction() does not execute if it is combined with the other function (as posted above)

Comment: Thank you for replying. In order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including your current script for replicating your issue?

Comment: ok, i added a link

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. I saw your shared spreadsheet. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your script, I couldn't understand about `The error message is gone but myfunction() does not execute if it is combined with the other function (as posted above)`. Because the script inluded in the shared Spreadsheet is the same with that of your question. Can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including your current script for replicating your issue? If you cannot understand my English, please tell me.

Comment: Hello @mtnrocky your functions are defined in the same Apps Script file but never executed together. You should write a `main()` function that runs the two functions. Is this causing an error? If so please post the errors in your question.

Comment: hi alessandro, thank you! you articulated my question better. Can you point me to documentation showing how to do that? I'm struggling to find it.

Comment: This is what i mean:
`function main() {
 lootorawtofinalforqbse();
 myFunction();
}`
[Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles) you can find some samples of Apps Script programming. Let me know if this is causing you a problem to propose a proper solution based on this assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Function Declaration

You are declaring two functions in your Apps Script Project:

```
function lootorawtofinalforqbse() {
//...
}

function myFunction() {
//...
}
```

These two functions are now declared. A function declaration tells the Apps Script engine about a function's name, return type, and parameters.

### Function Execution

To run a declared function you can use the Apps Script [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) feature: From the top menu `Run>Run Function>{Function Name}` where {Function Name} could be one of the declared function names. Since your goal is to execute these two function in order, I would recommend to declare a third function: `main()`.

In programming the `main()` function is a standard entry-point for programs. Its main goal is to execute multiple functions that will achieve the program functionality.

So your `main()` function would look like this:

```
function main() {  

    lootorawtofinalforqbse();  

    myFunction(); 
}
```

### Solution

Running the `main()` function from the Apps Script IDE you will achieve the ordered execution of your two functions.

### Other Examples

[Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles) you will find other examples on how to program using Google Apps Script